# Load multiple models within same function of controller code igniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a page where I want to display dynamic two select boxes.One select box get data from one model and then other select box get from other.Then after getting the data it will save the query or result of both of them and then view into one view page .

I want to save the data in array of two queries and this is my controller:

```
 function index(){

    $data['main_content'] = 'stockInView';



    $this->load->model('itemsModel');
    $query2 = $this->itemsModel->getAllItems();
    if ($query2)
    {
        $data['records'] = $query2;

    }

    $this->load->model('categoryModel');
    $query = $this->categoryModel->getAllCategories();
    if ($query)
    {
        $data['records'] = $query;

    }


    $this->load->view('dashboardTemplate/template',$data); 
    }
```

And then I display them in a foreach loop . But it is only able to display the 2nd query results or in this case display only categories in one select box and not the items in other select box.I am doing this for the first time so I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Сhange the line `$data['records'] = $query2;` when working with category model to a different `$data` array element key like this:

```
$this->load->model('itemsModel');
$query2 = $this->itemsModel->getAllItems();
if ($query2)
{
    $data['itemRecords'] = $query2;
}

$this->load->model('categoryModel');
$query = $this->categoryModel->getAllCategories();
if ($query)
{
    $data['categoryRecords'] = $query;
}

$this->load->view('dashboardTemplate/template',$data);
```

Then in your view you use `$itemRecords` and `$categoryRecords` arrays to output them to their select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing the value of $data['records'] = $query2; with $data['records'] = $query;
So end you will only get second value. You should different array fields like 
$data['records2'] = $query2;
$data['records'] = $query2;

Comment: ohh.. thanks a lot.. ok tell me how can i do this.. if i select one option from first select box then it will give me options in 2nd select box according to that.. i think it will be done by applying the onchange function of  javascript.. i dont know how to i do it here ,, and also if it will be done without refresing by using ajax or jquery then it will be more good

Comment: @user1972143 this is a completely different topic, learn AJAX to update the second select box values when selecting a value from the first one, it can be easily achieved with jQuery, there are lots of information regarding this available

Answer (score 0):

You have two model which is **itemsModel** and **categoryModel**. If you load this two model in construct function then these two model are all time loded in this controller. So you can load this two model in Construct function. 
have a look the following code....

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('itemsModel');
    $this->load->model('categoryModel');
}

public function index() {

    $data['main_content'] = 'stockInView';

    $query2 = $this->itemsModel->getAllItems();
    if ($query2) {
        $data['itemRecords'] = $query2;
    }

    $query = $this->categoryModel->getAllCategories();
    if ($query) {
        $data['categoryRecords'] = $query;
    }


    $this->load->view('dashboardTemplate/template', $data);
}
```